# How set and get var with Path?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I write script for deploy files by ssh via Jenkins

```
#!groovy

node('superhost01'){
    String HOSTNAME="host01"
    String USERNAME="tech_user"
    withEnv(['PATH=/data/jdbc_connector'])
    stage('Prepare') {
        checkout scm
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        sh """
        scp -r config.yaml ${USERNAME}@${HOSTNAME}:$PATH
        """
}

}
```

BUT Jenkins returned error in line

```
withEnv(['PATH=/data/jdbc_connector'])
```

error:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on superhost01 in /data/jenkins/workspace/jdbc_connector
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no body to invoke
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsStepContext.newBodyInvoker(CpsStepContext.java:283)
```

how to correctly assign the value of a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withEnv` doesn't persist environment variables.  Instead, you need to tell `withEnv` what steps to run with that environment by passing it a block.   Here is what I think you want your code to look like:

```
#!groovy

node('superhost01'){
  String HOSTNAME="host01"
  String USERNAME="tech_user"
  withEnv(['PATH=/data/jdbc_connector']) {
    stage('Prepare') {
      checkout scm
    }

    stage('Deploy') {
      sh """
      scp -r config.yaml ${USERNAME}@${HOSTNAME}:$PATH
      """
    }
  }
}
```

As a side note, I suspect you actually want to set `PATH` to `/data/jdbc_connector:$PATH`, otherwise your checkout step will not be able to find git and your deploy step will not be able to find scp.